# loosing rows in pandas dataframe after apply method that doesnt delete row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.3

I am loading 30000 lines from a file and load them into pandas dataframe.
before putting them into the dataframe,i counted them,they are 30000,i load them into dataframe,and count them again,i still get the same number.
However because there missing values,i ve put apply function on some of the columns to deal with missing values and unparsable values to int or float.
After that i count them again and i ve found out that i am remaining with only near 3000.
My question is ,does the apply method delete rows that are not specified in the conditions cited.?

here is my code for adding them

```
print(counter)
users=pd.DataFrame(users,columns=names.split('\t'))
print(users.shape[0])
user_ids=set(list(map(int,user_ids)))
users['id']=users['id'].astype('int64')
users['career_level']=users['career_level'].apply(lambda c:0 if c=='NULL' or c==''  else int(c))
users['discipline_id']=users['discipline_id'].apply(lambda c:0 if c=='NULL' or c==''  else int(c))
users['industry_id']=users['industry_id'].apply(lambda c:0 if c=='NULL' or c=='' else int(c))
users['experience_years_experience']=users['experience_years_experience'].apply(lambda c:0 if c=='NULL' or c=='' else int(c))
users['experience_n_entries_class']=users['experience_n_entries_class'].apply(lambda c:0 if c=='NULL' or c=='' else  int(c))
users['experience_years_in_current']=users['experience_years_in_current'].apply(lambda c:0 if c=='NULL' or c==''  else int(c))
users['edu_degree']=users['edu_degree'].apply(lambda c:0 if c=='NULL' or c==''  else int(c))
users=users[users['id'].isin(user_ids)]
print(users.shape[0])
```

and here is the result

```
30000
30000
2926
```

The first 30k are the counter that of the object users 
the second 30k is the size of the dataframe
and the 2k is after using the function apply.

I would appreciate a lot if you any one could tell me whats going on.

Comment: that's the answer: `users=users[users['id'].isin(user_ids)]`. Add `print(len(user_ids))` to your script

Comment: i just noticed after putting writing the question